# Is there any solution to wait for nested forEach until return result using async/await in node.js

Tags: node.js, callback, async-await, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on FCM and need device tokens for all member in channel/room to send push notifications and every member have multiple devices, for that i need two for loop.

I'm using async/await with firestore queries but it not wait for result, process it in background and move to next statement which need result data.

```
const notification = async (channelId) => {
    let tokens = []
    const members = await db.collection('channels/' + channelId + '/members').get();
    await members.forEach(async (member) => {
        const deviceTokens = await db.collection('users/' + member.id + '/devices').get();
        await deviceTokens.forEach(async (token) => {
            console.log(token.id);
            await tokens.push(token.data().token);
        })
    })
    console.log(tokens);
    return await sendPush(tokens); // calling other functions
}
```

I expect the output is tokens = ['token1', 'token2', 'token3'], but the actual output is tokens = []

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: @estus i asked about nested forEach please have a look

Comment: I am also stuck with this problem but not find any solution.

Comment: @Umar It doesn't matter if it's nested or not. You shouldn't use forEach together with async/await, that's the point, this is explained in dupe question.

Comment: @estus you are absolutely right but problem is that firestore returned array only works with forEach, was tried it with map, for..of.. , for..in.. 
but nothing work

Comment: I currently don't use Firebase and can't check if it's workable. I posted an answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`forEach` cannot be efficiently used together with `async..await`. Since a query returns [query snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), an array should be iterated instead. Promise chains can be executed in series with `for..of` or in parallel with `Promise.all` and array `map`, as explained in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop), e.g.:

```
const notification = async (channelId) => {
    let tokens = [];
    const members = await db.collection('channels/' + channelId + '/members').get();
    for (const member of members.docs) {
      const deviceTokens = await db.collection('users/' + member.id + '/devices').get();
      for (const deviceToken of deviceTokens.docs) {
        tokens.push(deviceToken.data().token);
      }
    }

    return await sendPush(tokens);
}
```

`await sendPush(...)` will work correctly only if `sendPush` returns a promise.

Comment: thankyou so much @estus 
you made my day, was making silly mistake , thanks again

Answer (score 4):

I guess you missunderstood the usage of async/await.

You can use await for functions that are async. `Array.forEach` is not an async function so you dont need to use it for your inner loop.

I would recommend to use promises here:

```
    async doStuff(){
        let tokens = [];
        const members = await db.collection('channels/' + channelId + '/members').get();

        let promises = members.map(member => {
            return db.collection('users/' + member.id + '/devices').get();
        })
        // or the forEach
        let promises = [];

        members.forEach(member => {
            promises.push(db.collection('users/' + member.id + '/devices').get());
        });

        Promise
            .all(promises)
            .then(values => {
                values.map(token => {
                    console.log(token.id);
                    tokens.push(token.data().token);
                });

                sendPush(tokens);
            })
    }
```

Now you gather all the `members` then start for all `members` the token requests and when `all()` of them finished you can push your tokens in that array and send them.

Comment: Using map instead of forEach and ignoring a value it returns is an antipattern. It already returns an array - at least it should if `members` is an array. Also this code won't result in correctly chained promises.

Comment: changed that map return, idk if op wants to get a return value from that function or not

Comment: @BraveButter array.map not work with firestore query result

Comment: you can change that to forEach that should be no problem